# Problems with inserting home directory in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.6

I need to add a directory in home at the beginning of a python program. The problem is that when I'm using different machines I need to edit that line every time to match the right username.

e.g:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user_foo/directory')
```

on computer 1

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user_bar/directory')
```

on computer 2

Is there a way in Python3 to get the user name? Or am I doomed to rewrite this line each time I pull it from git on another machine with a different user?

Comment: used this: sys.path.insert(0,  os.path.expanduser('~') + '/directory')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'mydir'))
```

Comment: thanks! I did it a bit different but this way also seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/%s/directory'%user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would have marked it as accepted but I used another way to get to the home directory.

Comment: That is okay :)